# Separate alphabets and numbers from a string

Tags: php

```
$str = 'ABC300';
```

How I can get values like

```
$alphabets = "ABC";
$numbers = 333;
```

Comment: Will the pattern always be 3 numbers followed by 3 letters?

Comment: `$alphabets = ABC;` unless you want that to evaluate as a constant, you probably meant `$alphabets = "ABC";`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: No, it will be dynamic. Alphabets will be in begining ang numbers at the end.

Comment: `list($alphabets, $numbers) = sscanf($str, '%[A-Z]%d');`

Comment: @amitshree     check `is_numeric` and `ctype_digit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a idea , first remove numbers from the string and save in a variable. then remove alphabets from the $str variable and save. try the code

```
 $str = 'ABC300';
$alf= trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'',$str));//removes number from the string 
$number = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z]+/', '', $str);// removes alphabets from the string 
echo $alf,$number;// your expected output
```

Comment: You'll need `[A-Za-z]` or the `i` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to find all digits and use the array to replace original string with the digits inside.

For example

```
function extractDigits($string){
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);

    return $match[0];
}

$str = 'abcd1234ab12';
$digitsArray = extractDigits($str);
$allAlphas = str_replace($digitsArray,'',$str);
$allDigits = '';
foreach($digitsArray as $digit){
   $allDigits .= $digit;
}
```

Comment: Don't need the character class and have a typo, `($str):`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (it's not that fast)...

```
$string = "ABCDE3883475";
$numbers = "";
$alphabets = "";
$strlen = strlen($string);
for($i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++) {
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    if(is_numeric($char)) {
        $numbers .= $char;
    } else {
        $alphabets .= $char;
    }
}
```

Then all numbers should be in `$numbers` and all alphabetical characters should be in `$alphabets` ;)

https://3v4l.org/Xh4FR